# How to install recovery for S7 when in bootloop and not recognized by USB

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, samsung-galaxy-s7

My Samsung Galaxy S7 (SM-G930F) that was installing LineageOS 18.1 is stuck in a bootloop and I can not get into recovery or pretty much do anything. I can, however, get into download mode, but the phone is not recognized by USB connection. (From what I read a year ago, I think that this is an issue with some Samsung Galaxy S7 phones. It has not worked for a while).

Is there a way to install/get in recovery without a USB connection (since the USB is not recognized). The USB connection does put power into the device so the issue is likely with the connection and data transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to drain down the battery and in that manner get into recovery mode.

Update: also realized that the following may work. VolUp+VolDown+Home+Power eventually puts into reboot, and then Jump in and do VolUp+Home+Powerand when Samsung logo comes, let go of power. This is a touch-and-go and may not always work. Needs considerable artistry to make it work.